# fechas timestamp problemas a la hora de convertir

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Tengo almacenadas las "fechas"(es un varchar) y necesito llevarlo a otro formato para hacer operaciones, ya pobre muchas opciones y la que parecia que me ayudaria dateformat me arroga valores en ceros, tambien tengo que conservar las horas y minutos,el sistema va a estar en php,en otro php que uso fechas me funciono el strtotime,me imagino que las / voy a tener que remplazarlas por "-"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto imagnes de la base, lo que tengo que hacer es mover de fecha a fecha nueva[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que tal asi es la fecha esta en la db pero el sistema esta en php y pense que si no se podia con mysql hacerlo con php pero ya me dieron la  respuesta correcta,mil gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar la siguiente función:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("19/04/2018 18:30:01", '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Obtiene un campo **string** y devuelve su campo **date** correspondiente. Puedes comprobar la documentación de esta función en el siguiente [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp).

Comment: gracias hermano es lo que estaba buscando me ahorraste tiempo!

Comment: De nada, si te sirvió la respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada.